# set size of children of a StackPanel not respected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal" set in the XAML.
When I add items to it's Children they are not being rendered at their pre-set size.
The items I'm adding are a class derived from Canvas, with an Image (Stretch=Uniform) and a TextBlock in a vertical StackPanel as the only child. I explicitly set the Width and Height of the Canvas, I can see the correct values when debugging, but they are being rendered much larger (looks like Stretched to fit?).
What am I doing wrong?

Code below - sorry about the formatting, but trying to enclose in code quotes doesn't seem to work from my Mac!

```
<Border BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Grid.Row="0"
        CornerRadius="0, 12, 0, 0">
   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="navScroller">
      <StackPanel x:Name="navPanel" Background="White" Orientation="Horizontal"> 
          <Button Style="{StaticResource GlassButton}" Height="30" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="homeBtn"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30"
                  Click="HomeBtn_Click" Margin="4,4,4,4" >
              <Image Source="{StaticResource homeImg}"></Image>
           </Button>
      </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

for the class derived from Canvas :-

```
public IconView(string filePath, double sze)
{
    this._myPath = filePath;
    this.IsDir = isDir;
    mySize = sze;
    //Trace.WriteLine(_myPath);
    string foldername = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = foldername;
    tb.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    tb.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    sp.Children.Add(GetThumbnail());
    sp.Children.Add(tb);
    this.Children.Add(sp);
    this.Width = mySize;
    this.Height = mySize * 1.4;
    this.PreviewMouseUp += IconView_PreviewMouseUp;
    this.PreviewTouchUp += IconView_PreviewTouchUp;

    this.Margin = new Thickness(10);

}
```

to add to the StackPanel :-

```
IconView iv = new IconView(path, 20);
Trace.WriteLine("iv size = " + iv.Width + " x " + iv.Height);
iv.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
iv.Height = 20;
iv.Width = 20;
iv.Margin = new Thickness(20,10,20,10);
navPanel.Children.Add(iv);
```

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.** - Use an `ItemsControl` if you need items or the like.

Comment: Please elaborate... I have to add the items in code as they will change depending on user interaction. Should I use a (horizontal) ListView instead of the StackPanel? I'm a bit lost here - all the documentation says that a StackPanel respects the size of its Children if this is set, but that's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Hoverfrog if you need an "items-based" UI, then use an `ItemsControl`. and yes, a `StackPanel` is a Layout-related element, not something you put "items" into. See [ItemsControl](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) and [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @HighCore dude, just go make a permanent blog post or something with that line as the title and a quick explanation as to why etc so it can be referenced with a quick copy/paste like people do with the "what have you tried" thing. It gets used enough it would make sense too. ;)

Comment: ah ah ah HighCore - how do I set an ItemsControl as the host for my UI-based horizontally based host?

Comment: re-wrote it as an ItemsControl with data-binding, surprisingly easily! Still can't get the items to display at the correct size, in spite of setting explicit height and width in a Style set with ItemContainerStyle